# How can I change color depending on health?

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to know how to edit  my script below to make the color lower  or higher depending on the health amount instead of a set amount in the script. Everything works currently, i'm just trying to edit the script to do what I said above.

```
local parts = script.Parent.Parent:WaitForChild("Collectables"):GetChildren()

for i, v in pairs(parts) do
    if v:IsA("Part") then
        if v:WaitForChild("ClickDetector") then
            if v:FindFirstChild("Values") then
                local Values = v:FindFirstChild("Values")
                Values.Red.Value = 0
                Values.Green.Value = 255
                Values.Blue.Value = 0
                Values.Health.Value = 100
                Values.Change.Value = true
                v.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = 100
                Values.Color.Value = Color3.fromRGB(Values.Red.Value,Values.Green.Value,Values.Blue.Value)
                v.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.TextColor3 = Values.Color.Value
                v.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
                    if Values.Health.Value > 5 then
                        Values.Health.Value -= 5
                    else
                        v:Destroy()
                    end
                    if v:FindFirstChild("SurfaceGui") then
                        v.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = v.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text - 5
                        if Values.Change.Value == true then
                            if Values.Red.Value < 250 then
                                Values.Red.Value += 50
                            elseif Values.Red.Value == 250 then
                                Values.Red.Value += 5
                            elseif Values.Red.Value == 255 and Values.Green.Value > 5 then
                                Values.Green.Value -= 50
                            elseif Values.Green.Value == 5 then
                                Values.Green.Value -= 5
                                Values.Change.Value = false
                            end
                            Values.Color.Value = Color3.fromRGB(Values.Red.Value,Values.Green.Value,Values.Blue.Value)
                            v.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.TextColor3 = Values.Color.Value
                        end
                    end
                end)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use your stepwise function for calculating the color, a more simple way to handle this might be to define the colors you want ahead of time or simplify it down to ranges of colors based on health. Like,

- if it's between 100 - 60, the color is green.
- if it's between 60 - 30, it's yellow.
- if it's less than 30, it is red.

And to make the color react to the health, I would set up a series of dependencies using the [Changed signal](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/NumberValue#Changed) on your NumberValue objects.

The ClickDetector's only job is to modify the health of the block. But when the health changes, the color values change. And when the color values change, the text color changes too.

First off, delete the R, G, and B NumberValues, you can set the text color without them.

```lua
local DEFAULT_HEALTH = 100
local HEALTH_PER_CLICK = 5
-- colors are sorted by health in descending order, add more as desired
local COLORS = {
    { health = 60, color = Color3.fromRGB(  0, 255, 0)}, -- green
    { health = 30, color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 0)}, -- yellow
    { health =  0, color = Color3.fromRGB(255,   0, 0)}, -- red
}

local function observeHealthChanges(values, textLabel)
    -- whenever the health changes, update the text and the text color
    local health = values.Health
    health.Changed:Connect(function(newValue)
        textLabel.Text = tostring(newValue)

        -- set the color based on the health by looping through the colors to find the right ones
        for i, colorData in ipairs(COLORS) do
            local colorRange = colorData.health
            local healthColor = colorData.color
            if newValue > colorRange then
                textLabel.TextColor3 = healthColor
                break
            end
        end
    end)
end

local function observeClicks(part, values, detector)
    local health = values.Health

    -- listen for clicks to reduce the health            
    detector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
        if health.Value > HEALTH_PER_CLICK then
            health.Value -= HEALTH_PER_CLICK
        else
            part:Destroy()
        end
    end)
end

local parts = script.Parent.Parent:WaitForChild("Collectables"):GetChildren()
for _, v in ipairs(parts) do
    -- escape if the object isn't a part
    if v:IsA("Part") then
        
        -- escape if the part doesn't have Values, a ClickDetector, and a SurfaceGui
        local Values = v.Values
        local Detector = v.ClickDetector
        local Gui = v.SurfaceGui
        if Values and Detector and Gui then
        
            -- register the change listeners
            local textLabel = v.SurfaceGui.TextLabel
            observeHealthChanges(Values, textLabel)
            observeClicks(v, Values, Detector)

            -- set the health and all the rest will follow
            Values.Health.Value = DEFAULT_HEALTH
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I just put it in my game, and this wasnt working. Is it meant to be in a local script? It is in a seperate folder in a regular script.

Comment: Should work like your original Script. What isn't working? Are the changed signals firing? Are the colors incorrect?

Comment: All the events are firing, but the color is just red for the whole time and not changing. Red is not the set TextColor3 , so the script is working but its only  setting red

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, I haven't been able to work on my game for a while, but after putting print statements in, I noticed that the observeHealthChanges and observeClicks functions fire, but the  observeColorChanges function does not fire.

Comment: @TrulyBlue, I've updated my answer and simplified it. That should prevent the rgb signals from fighting with each other.

Comment: Now the function is firing, but the color still isnt changing. I know that its getting all the way to the 'if newValue > colorRange' statement. The 'healthColor' is getting set to 1, 0, 0

Comment: @TrulyBlue, That makes sense `pairs` doesn't guarantee order. I've updated the answer to use a list and `ipairs`

Comment: It works now. Thanks for the help, and updating your solution multiple times when it didn't work. I've seen you around the Stack Overflow Lua community a lot, and this helps a lot.